# Nested SELECT with IN

Tags: mysql

I am using Mysql and trying to migrate data from one DB to other. I have not worked on databases earlier.

This query gives me close to 300 results

```
select distinct internal_id from ratingsapp.hotel03
```

But this one returns no results and has no errors either:

```
select restname from City.resturant where restid not in 
    (select distinct internal_id from ratingsapp.hotel03)
```

Now if I manually pick few internal_ids from the hotel03 table, and put this in place of the nested query, the query returns proper results. I am not sure what exactly am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when one of the values is `NULL`. So this might work:

```
select restname
from City.resturant
where restid not in (select distinct internal_id from ratingsapp.hotel03 where internal_id is not null);
```

Another way to write this query is with `not exists`:

```
select restname
from City.resturant r
where not exists (select 1
                  from ratingsapp.hotel03 h
                  where h.internal_id = r.restid
                 );
```

The way this works, `NULL` is handled correctly without directly checking for it.  That is one reason why `NOT EXISTS` is preferable to `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not because all the `restid` from `City.restaurant` are in `internal_id` of `ratingsapp.hotel03` ? You say that you manually pick a few of these ids and there was a result, but check this:

```
distinct City.restaurant.restid: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
distinct ratingsapp.hotel03.internal_id: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Then your query will return nothing, as all the `restid` are **not** `not in` the `internal_id`. But if you pick *a few ids* from `ratingsapp.hotel03.internal_id`, for instance:

```
select restname
from City.resturant
where restid not in (1, 2, 3)
```

Then you will have all the `City.restaurant` with a `restid` of 4 or 5!